# Worklight Cordova storage NaN values

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, nan, web-sql

I'm starting to be crazy because of my app's database. In this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359463/ibm-worklight-api-cordova-storage-sql-error-could-not-execute-statement-due-t) I explained the first problem of it. Now I have another problem: when I store data retrieved from localhost db, in several columns of string type (`varchar` or `text`) I get the `NaN` value. I tried to invert the insert (for example i inserted a value of `columnA` in the `columnB` and vice versa) and seems that can be a problem of table structure. I noticed also that the columns with NaN values are continuous. Here an example of what happens:

```
INSERT INTO table(columnA,columnB,columnC,columnD)
           VALUES('blabla','mymy','20,21','sometext');
INSERT INTO table(columnA,columnB,columnC,columnD)
           VALUES('word','ohoh','20','sometextother');

id columnA columnB columnC columnD
1  blabla  NaN     NaN     NaN
2  word    NaN     20      NaN
.  ...     ...     ...     ...
```

if i insert values of `columnA` in `columnB` and vice versa i get this:

```
id columnA columnB columnC columnD
1  mymy    NaN     NaN     NaN
2  ohoh    NaN     20      NaN
.  ...     ...     ...     ...
```

the structure's table can be seen in topic which I mentioned on top of this post.

Comment: It looks like the above insert statements are sort of pseudocode you wrote to be able to explain your answer. Do you happen to have the exact insert statements that were used? If you know where the sqlite database is on disk, you can open the database and do a '.dump' to get the actual statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your insert statement:

```
for(var i=0;i<item.invocationResult.resultSet.length;i++){
            WL.Logger.debug(i+")Sto inserendo " + item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].titolo + "," + item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].autore + "," + item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].id_categoria);
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO canti(titolo,autore,id_categoria,testo) " +
                    "VALUES('"+item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].titolo+"','" +
                            +item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].autore+"','" +
                            +item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].id_categoria+"','" +
                            +item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].testo+"')");
        }
```

Observe the following lines:

```
+item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].titolo+"','" +
+item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].autore+"','" +
+item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].id_categoria+"','" +
+item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].testo+
```

You have included a '+' at the beginning of each line AND at the end of the previous line. The first '+' will be used as string concatenation, but the second '+' will be interpreted by javascript as a 'convert to integer'.

For example if you type the following into your javascript debugger:

```
+"54"
```

the result will be '54', since this is saying "convert the string '54' into an integer"

However if you type this:

```
+"hello"
```

the result will be NaN, since "hello" cannot be converted into an integer.

So the solution is to use this instead:

```
for(var i=0;i<item.invocationResult.resultSet.length;i++){
            WL.Logger.debug(i+")Sto inserendo " + item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].titolo + "," + item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].autore + "," + item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].id_categoria);
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO canti(titolo,autore,id_categoria,testo) " +
                    "VALUES('"item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].titolo+"','" +
                           item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].autore+"','" +
                           item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].id_categoria+"','" +
                           item.invocationResult.resultSet[i].testo+"')");
        }
```

Not tested, but you get the idea.

Also, since you have Worklight tagged on this questions, I'd highly recommend looking into [JSONStore](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/05_08_JSONStore_-_The_client_side_JSON_based_database_overview.pdf) for your local storage needs.

Comment: i didn't notice this particular. in effect the editor can have added the other '+' when i formatted the code on pressing enter key. this would explain the stange behavior after insertion of the first column. i'll edit at once.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that those columns are marked as integer values, so it is trying to parse the strings for numbers, and since they are not (except for the 20 in the second value of column C), it gives you Not a Number (NaN). Make sure that the schema says string values and not integers.

Comment: the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359463/ibm-worklight-api-cordova-storage-sql-error-could-not-execute-statement-due-t) i posted on top of my post shows the code of the structure of my db.